# "ValueError: Your Layer or Model is in an invalid state." after upgrading to tensorflow federated 0.17.0 from 0.16.1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am running into an error after upgrading to TFF 0.17.0. The same code works perfectly in TFF 0.16.1. The training works just fine in both versions however when I try to copy weights from the FL state to model to evaluate it on test dataset, I get the following error:

```
File "fl/main_fl.py", line 166, in keras_evaluate                                                                 
    loss, accuracy = self.model.evaluate(test_dataset, verbose=0)                                                                             
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 905, in evaluate
    self._assert_built_as_v1()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 852, i$ _assert_built_as_v1
    (type(self),))
ValueError: Your Layer or Model is in an invalid state. This can happen for the following cases:
 1. You might be interleaving estimator/non-estimator models or interleaving models/layers made in tf.compat.v1.Graph.as_default() with model$/layers created outside of it. Converting a model to an estimator (via model_to_estimator) invalidates all models/layers made before the conv$rsion (even if they were not the model converted to an estimator). Similarly, making a layer or a model inside a a tf.compat.v1.Graph invalid$tes all layers/models you previously made outside of the graph.
2. You might be using a custom keras layer implementation with  custom __init__ which didn't call super().__init__.  Please check the impleme$tation of <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional'> and its bases.
```

Below is my keras_evaluate method:

```
    def keras_evaluate(self, test_dataset, mode='test', step=0):
        self.state.model.assign_weights_to(self.model)
        loss, accuracy = self.model.evaluate(test_dataset, verbose=0)
        print('Mode={}, Loss={}, Accuracy={}'.format(mode, loss, accuracy))
```

self.state is the state returned by tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process i.e tff.templates.IterativeProcess, test_dataset is of type tf.data.Dataset and self.model is tf.keras.Model type i.e keras functional model. I have one custom layer however it does have super() method so point 2 in the error is misleading me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try instead using `tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation` with the same `model_fn` as you use with your training. I guess the `self.model` you are assigning into was built in a different graph context which confuses Keras.

Comment: Was this issue solved? If yes, I'd love to know. I am using tff as well and ending up with the same error when I save my model.